# Windows Update 659 - 12/04/2011

Tags: windows-7, updates

[image]

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's about administrative privileges message (I had this issue with Redistributables on games etc). However this is a solo admin account with UAC disabled (UAC driver is active though). How can I solve this?

Comment: See this link, you may be Infected...http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_update/windows-7-error-codes-80070659-659-cant-install/e0564d1f-315b-4f17-9f30-bbd38953f7d3

Comment: Or it could be 3rd party Security Software causing it.

Comment: If you cannot solve it in a reasonable amount of time, you can get Free Windows Update Support from MS...https://support.microsoft.com/oas/default.aspx?LN=en-us&gprid=6527&x=18&y=11&st=1&wfxredirect=1&sd=gn

Comment: I read somewhere that it could be a sign of infection but I really take good care of my computer. It was something on the current Redist. that blocked the installation. The tip from Etmare worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with the last (April 2011) Windows update, especially the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package on my Windows 7 64-bit system. The solution was very simple:

1. Uninstall the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package via the Control Panel
2. Manually download the Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package from:
   http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms11-025.mspx
3. Install the new file again